# Can a sentry prevent a boss from healing while you are out of a fight?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

On inferno difficulty, uniques and champions will automatically heal back to full after a certain amount of time if you aren't actively fighting them (10 seconds or so).  If I were to drop a sentry before I die, can this keep the boss engaged enough to prevent them from healing up in time for me to get back into the fight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the Sentry depsawn when you die.

It is on the other hand possible to extend the reset timer with a follower the restart timer will not start untill the follower is knocked down.

At least that is what I have been experiencing.

Comment: Do you mean 'followers' like Leah? Because Kormac, Lyndon & Eirena keel over right when I do

Comment: Leah, Tyrael, the Scoundrel, the Templar what ever you have following you. Yes most of them die like a bug on a windscreen but regardless if they manage to stay a live it extends the reset timer